# User spamming chatbot answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The user Serg Z. is currently spamming answers copy-pasted from chatbot output (perhaps with slight modifications).

They have recently deleted two examples (users with 10K rep can see these) after I asked them what was going on. Here is the first one:

[Subgroups of the $p$-adics that miss $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739092/subgroups-of-the-p-adics-that-miss-mathbbz)

Is there nothing that can be done about this?

Comment: Here is the other (just deleted) example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740239/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-sum-involving-a-positive-diagonal-times-skew-symmetric

Comment: The user's other answers are to more elementary questions; I suspect but am not completely sure that these are also chatbot generated. Here is the user page for those without 10K reputation: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1202278/serg-z

Comment: Ah, I guess there really isn't anything to be done since the moderators are all on strike...

...largely because stack exchange is refusing to take the problem of chatbot-generated content seriously.

Comment: The current policy from our SE overlords is that we are not permitted to moderate material simply for the reason that it is generated by chat bots.  This, among other reasons, is the motivation behind the current [moderation spike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/).  If you believe that this kind of content is harmful to the site, I would encourage you to use the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page to get in touch with Trust & Safety, and let them know what you think of GenAI generated content.

Comment: Try looking at the [activity page](https://stackexchange.com/users/6123746/serg-z?tab=activity), as of now.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, it's not just math.stackexchange that's being spammed.

Comment: "current moderation spike" Funny typo.

Comment: We couldn't even prevent them from answering *this question*! (For those unaware, there is a deleted answer to this question which was posted by the same user whose name is mentioned in the post as a spammer. Ironically, the answer presents a few suggestions on "how to handle the situation", and also looks like it was spat out by a chat-bot). Note that we still deleted the answer using the usual channel of downvote-and-delete, but if removal is not an option then nothing can be done. Nevertheless, thank you for spotting the user.

Comment: What should be the appropriate response to @SergZ 's answers here on meta, to a question about that user? Downvoting if disagree, maybe; but deletion by others for three instances? Should that user at least be allowed to answer this meta question about them?

Comment: @peterwhy I would appreciate a sincere explanation from Serg Z., but none of the answers deleted so far are anything more than pure trolling. Do you disagree?

Comment: @Stephen My opinion on whether those answers are useful would be reflected by my votes, if I can vote. But I am not convinced yet that their explanation answers should be hidden, even if they choose to explain via generated text. Outside meta in the main site for factually incorrect answers, I would tend to agree with you more.

Comment: @peterwhy I have undeleted one of those answers, which I perhaps judged too early. You may now see the most reasonable answer the user has posted. Note that they have posted four answers, two of which are marked as rude/abusive and a fourth one which consists of philosophical idioglossia and has nothing to do with the matter at hand. The one I'm undeleting appeared first chronologically.

Comment: @peterwhy For me here in meta the distinction is not between factually correct and factually incorrect, but rather between answers that sincerely address the question and those that are intended only to provoke.

Comment: "Should that user at least be allowed to answer this meta question about them?" They were. Multiple times. If you want to argue that you should be allowed to read them, that would come at the cost of others having to deal with them. I personally don't know how they got closed, but clearly enough people judged that that balancing act favored closing them.

Comment: Frankly, unless it is because all the moderators are on strike, the user's behavior on meta alone would normally be enough to get them banned, ChatGPT or no ChatGPT.

Comment: I would take issue with the word "spamming" in your title and lead sentence.  Flagging spam is in the context of StackExchange based on dodgy links and solicitations, rather than on inept ramblings of chatbots or (perhaps) human posers.

Comment: @hardmath I was using spamming in the sense of online gaming culture, meaning repeated voluminous use of the same action (in thid case, posting chatbot generated answers over and over). I can see that perhaps my choice of terminology was unfortunate, given the existence of the flags.

Comment: The undeleted answer reached a score of $-19$ before being self-deleted by the author. I regret having undeleted it in the first place, but I hope that showed some users here that the answer was not in good faith. It lacked an admission that the user is responsible for the acts, and it also (to the best of my detection abilities) looked like it was generated by a chat-bot. The subsequent answers by the same user (I shared their history above) are closer to trolling than even to smugness, and if I see any more answers by said user I'm going to be voting to delete them as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't know if this is worthy to have another thread for it, I don't use Meta much so please excuse me if I'm breaking some rule, but this user [Zoonnie Zonn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1203226/zoonnie-zonn) seems to also be spamming chatbot-like answers.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you for the alert. A significant number of these answers are wrong, and the style of writing is definitely very chatbot-like. It might be a particular type of chat-bot as well. Phrases like "youngsters these days" and the first paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741509/find-the-mean-of-determinant-of-matrix-with-random-elements/4741512#4741512) also seem very artificial. To the best of my efforts, this is probably chatbot-generated.

Comment: How the hell has the general public gotten the idea that ChatGPT can understand/do mathematics?

Comment: Hey folks, I've handled this situation for now and left an answer on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391587/1037447) confirming that our Inauthentic Usage policy applies to purposefully disruptive actions, irrespective of GPT usage.

Comment: @Obie2.0 "Frankly, unless it is because all the moderators are on strike, the user's behavior on meta alone would normally be enough to get them banned, ChatGPT or no ChatGPT"  Indeed, this seems to be a correct assessment.

Comment: @MathCrackExchange Two things contribute to this notion (1) The fact that the general public doesn't know much advanced mathematics. ChatGPT actually does do a decent enough job on questions say at the level of eighth or ninth grade mathematics, and the public thinks that's good enough (2) The fact that ChatGPT is capable of disguising its answer with good vocabulary and can "start" answers well by stating the basic theorems/results/definitions etc. : anyone with a low attention span is seeing that and falling for it.

Comment: the user is suspended now

Comment: Apparently that user is suspended only from math.SE, or the suspension was global but time-limited because they are back to their old tricks on other .SE sites.

Comment: Somehow the user was active yesterday, August 14th on Philosophy SE, but now is suspended for 100 years until July 21 2123, different dates, network wide.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The current policy makes it very difficult to discipline users merely for posting bad answers, even, or perhaps particularly, if those bad answers are the systematic product of limited language models.

*However*, the mere fact of using LLMs does *not* negate all policies around the Code of Conduct, trolling, and so forth. This user has also been writing hostile comments on various sites, accusing people critiquing their answers of "reading out of their posterior" or of being unintelligent and envious. They also have been reposting answers after their previous answers have been deleted, as with this very question. Some of the ChatGPT errors have also caused them to violate the Code of Conduct by claiming credit for the work of others, such as one answer that implies that they invented the theory of relativity.

Finally, some of these answers are so far from the content of the question as to be "not an answer" on their own merits, as with their most recent answer to this question, which appears to be pseudo-Buddhist musings mostly unconnected to the question.

Any of these activities could be subject to moderation whether or not they were using ChatGPT. A user engaging in this sort of behavior without AI would certainly be sent to cool down for a bit, and I think the same can be applied to those users who violate the site rules while incidentally using LLM content generators.

Comment: Someone has to be first, I guess.

Comment: @ScottRowe - In what sense?

Comment: You knew this kind of thing would happen eventually.

Comment: This is a first?  And who is Obie 2.0?